# How to write subquery in FROM using eloquent?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I want to merge the subquery to my main query

This is my raw query

```
select field1, field3, total
from (select field1, field3, sum(field2) as total
      from sales
      group by field1, field2
      having total <> 0
     ) s
group by field1;
```

I have tried to merge it

```
$sub = Sales::select(DB::raw('field1,field3,SUM(field2)as total'))         
            ->groupBy('field1',DB::raw('field3 having total<> 0'));  

 $main = DB::table(DB::raw("({$sub->toSql()}) as sub") )
            ->select('field1', 'field3','total');
            $main ->mergeBindings($sub->getQuery());
            $main ->groupBy('field1');       
            $main ->get();
```

But it doesn't return any data. What's wrong with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you aren't using Laravel 5.6 for the fromSub method mentioned in @DigitalDrifter's response, just include your sub query in the `from()` function

```
$sub = Sales::select(DB::raw('field1,field3,SUM(field2)as total'))         
        ->groupBy('field1',DB::raw('field3 having total<> 0'));

YourMainModel::query()
->select('field1', 'field3','total')
->from(DB::raw("({$sub->toSql()}) as sub"))
->mergeBindings($sub->getQuery())
->groupBy('field1')
->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using the fromRaw method :

```
$finalQuery = self::newQuery()->fromRaw("({$subQuery->toSql()}) as sub")
```